# Kinesis writing to ElasticSearch and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis

I am using AWS Kinesis to write to Elastic Search and taking S3 as the backup. So, it is writing to both the sources. But I observed one problem that it does not push to S3 at same time as when it pushes to Elastic Search. So, does it do periodically or something like that? Any explanation if anyone could give would be appreciated. Also, if this is the case, is there any way to change it?

Comment: how are you writing from kinesis to elasticsearch or s3?? using lamdas??

Comment: No. its direct. In Kinesis, you have a configuration to add a destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem here. So, there are configuration for each Elastic Search and S3 which defines when it would write to them. Check Buffer Size and Buffer Time.

It is mentioned in AWS Kinesis FAQ:-

**Q: What is buffer size and buffer interval?**

Amazon Kinesis Firehose buffers incoming streaming data to a certain size or for a certain period of time before delivering it to destinations. You can configure buffer size and buffer interval while creating your delivery stream. The buffer size is in MBs and ranges from 1MB to 128MB for Amazon S3 destination and 1MB to 100MB for Amazon Elasticsearch Service destination. Buffer interval is in seconds and ranges from 60 seconds to 900 seconds. Please note that in circumstances where data delivery to destination is falling behind data writing to delivery stream, Firehose raises buffer size dynamically to catch up and make sure that all data is delivered to the destination.

Source - https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/firehose/faqs/

So, in my case, settings were different and hence I was seeing delay in writing to S3.